# how to compare unicode date u'2006-07-23' format and 25-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM using python pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Basically the unicode format will get from the datepicker and `25-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM` this format from one column
my dataframe is:

```
query,status,received_date
a,closed,25-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
b,pending,27-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
ab,closed,28-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
bb,pending,29-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
```

and I will get two dates from datepicker like following format `(u'2015-06-23',u'2015-06-29')`. How to compare this unicode dates and recieved_date column.

I have to display datas between those two dates (that will get from datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first convert `dates` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then column `received_date` too and extract [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html). Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `mask` for filtering:

```
#datetimes changed for better testing
print df
  query   status                   received_date
0     a   closed  20-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
1     b  pending  27-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
2    ab   closed  28-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
3    bb  pending  30-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM

dates = (u'2015-06-23',u'2015-06-29')
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates).date
print dates
[datetime.date(2015, 6, 23) datetime.date(2015, 6, 29)]

df['received_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['received_date']).dt.date
print df
  query   status received_date
0     a   closed    2015-06-20
1     b  pending    2015-06-27
2    ab   closed    2015-06-28
3    bb  pending    2015-06-30

print (df['received_date'] > dates[0]) & (df['received_date'] < dates[1])
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: received_date, dtype: bool

df = df[(df['received_date'] > dates[0]) & (df['received_date'] < dates[1])]
print df
  query   status received_date
1     b  pending    2015-06-27
2    ab   closed    2015-06-28
```

But faster is modified [`PhilChang`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734115/2901002) solution:

```
dates = (u'2015-06-23',u'2015-06-29')
df['received_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['received_date'])
df = df.set_index('received_date')
return df[dates[0]:dates[1]]
```

**TESTING** (`len(df) == 40k`):

```
In [569]: %timeit a(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 12.2 s per loop

In [570]: %timeit b(df1)
10 loops, best of 3: 92.3 ms per loop

In [571]: %timeit c(df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.57 ms per loop
```

Code for testing:

```
#length is 40k
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

def a(df):
    dates = (u'2015-06-23',u'2015-06-29')
    df = df.set_index('received_date')
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
    return df[dates[0]:dates[1]]


def b(df):
    dates = (u'2015-06-23',u'2015-06-29')
    dates = pd.to_datetime(dates).date
    df['received_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['received_date']).dt.date
    df = df[(df['received_date'] > dates[0]) & (df['received_date'] < dates[1])]
    return df

def c(df):
    dates = (u'2015-06-23',u'2015-06-29')
    df['received_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['received_date'])
    df = df.set_index('received_date')
    return df[dates[0]:dates[1]]

print a(df)
print b(df1)
print c(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

convert them to datetime.

```
dates = (u'2015-06-23',u'2015-06-29')
df = df.set_index('received_date')
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df[dates[0]:dates[1]]
```

Comment: i have to compare unicode dates and received_date column

Comment: and displays datas between those dates

Comment: if i pick u'2015-06-23',u'2015-06-29' means it will display datas between those dates